# ERROR: sql: Scan error on column index 11, name "i.end_date": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type <nil> into type *time.Time

Tags: postgresql, go, grpc

**I have created table like this :**

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    id                  uuid,
    Test                BOOLEAN   NOT NULL,
    end_date            TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

My struct

```
type Issue struct {
    ID                uuid.UUID
    Test              bool
    EndDate           time.Time `db:"due_date"`
}
```

Now case is there was some date without `EndDate` in **live database** so now where I query to get `all data`  I am getting this error

`ERROR: sql: Scan error on column index 11, name "i.end_date": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type <nil> into type *time.Time`

I Don't getting any idea where issue can be .

**UPDATE**

If I use sql.NullTime and then I made a respoce mode like this

```
return &model.Issue{
        AssetOwnerID: id,
        DueDate :       time.Now().UTC().Truncate(time.Second)
    }
```

**I am getting this error**

```
 Cannot use 'time.Now().UTC().Truncate(time.Second)' (type Time) as type sql.NullTime
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [sql.NullTime](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullTime) type, as example:

```
import (
    "database/sql"
)


    type Issue struct {
        ID                uuid.UUID
        Test              bool
        EndDate           sql.NullTime `db:"due_date"`
    }
```

Then, you could use as examples:

**Read operation:**

```
    if i.EndDate.Valid {
        fmt.Println(i.EndDate.Time.Unix())
    } else {
        fmt.Println("nil endDate")
    }
```

**Write operation:**

```
        i.EndTime.Valid = true
        i.EndTime.Time = time.Unix(iEndTime, 0)
```

**UPDATE:**

You can create the struct as:

```
return &model.Issue{
        AssetOwnerID: id,
        DueDate: sql.NullTime{
            Time:  time.Now().UTC().Truncate(time.Second),
            Valid: true,
        }
```

Comment: I am using `EndDate.Unix` , but now getting this   `undefined (type sql.NullTime has no field or method Unix)`

Comment: Hi @FatimaFahad check my update, hope this help

Comment: Sir getting issues in assigning this values .   `Cannot use 'time.Now().UTC().Truncate(time.Second)' (type Time) as type sql.NullTime`   I  was assigning  current time this way

Comment: Hi @FatimaFahad I've added an example for read and write operations

Comment: Sir I got that thing , Just stuck on I want to assign it a current day timestamp . And I was doing like this    `time.Now().UTC().Truncate(time.Second)`  . but Now when I do this I am getting this issue   `Cannot use 'time.Now().UTC().Truncate(time.Second)' (type Time) as type sql.NullTim`

Comment: @FatimaFahad What about `i.EndTime.Time = time.Now().UTC().Truncate(time.Second)` ?

Comment: I have updated question with this issue . can you have a look please ?